# We could burninate the whole [workplace] down

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Today I learned about [Facebook Workplace](https://www.facebook.com/workplace/), as it was mentioned in one of the questions. As this is a separate service, I wanted to retag a question with more specific tag, but quickly discovered that we don't yet have a specific tag.

After doing a search I discovered that we have around 50 questions related to this topic, and people were using all kind of combination of tags. The most popular is [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) + [workplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workplace), which pushes people into use of this weird [workplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workplace) meta tag, which is one of those tags that are not very welcomed here.

I went and retagged all the questions with my newly created [facebook-workplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-workplace) tag. And added a small description to it's wiki page (I don't have rep to edit tags wiki, so it's still in review queue)

I think it makes sense to completely blacklist [workplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workplace) tag, so it doesn't reincarnate in a future.

Comment: Wait, so, you found a tag that had all on-topic questions, so you went on a massive retagging spree *without* consulting the community, and *now* you want to burninate/blacklist it? Why?? What was wrong with [workplace]? No one was misusing it; that's just something you *thought* might happen.

Comment: I was guided by the line I saw somewhere on a a create new tag popup, which say somehting like: don't create meta tags which are only used in pair with other tags, and [workplace] doesn't work well without [facebook], that was my thought process.

Comment: But i'm accepting that it was a mistake to go with editing before doing this post on meta

Comment: Sigh. Nobody understands what "meta" means. A meta tag is one that describes the *nature* or *type* of question, rather than its contents. Examples of meta tags are [homework], [beginner], [difficult], and [unanswered].

Comment: There's probably no harm in making the tag more specific in this case, but in general I agree with Cody that you should ask the community before editing 50 tags. Since it's not used anymore, it's probably not worth blacklisting the old tag unless it does keep popping up. It won't be suggested as a tag now since it doesn't have any usage.

Comment: You say "50" but I only saw 23 in your edit.  Additionally, SEDE is only reporting 17, but I'm not sure when the cutover is/was for SEDE and this tag.

Comment: Additionally I disagree with blacklisting.  There were only a handful of usages and its usage was likely very narrow.  The tag wiki could've used updating to clarify its usage, but from what I'm seeing, blacklisting (or even burnination) was a bit much.

Comment: **There's a big difference between burnination and blacklisting.** Burnination is what you've already done (the tag will be removed if there's no questions with the tag). Blacklisting is reserved for extreme cases where the tag keeps coming back, which is not applicable here.

Comment: @CodyGray Agree that it's not really a meta tag. Than would it make any difference if I was motivated by: `create compound tags using hyphens rather than spaces (like [visual-studio]) rather than multiple tags separated by spaces ([visual] [studio])` from help section?

Comment: Visual Studio is a product name, so it needs to be a single tag. Notice that the tag is not [microsoft-visual-studio] or [microsoft-windows], however.

Comment: @CodyGray i was kinda guided by [facebook-messenger] tag

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not trying to say that [facebook-workplace] is a *bad* tag. Maybe [workplace] should have been renamed to [facebook-workplace]. But, we have tools that will allow us to do tag renames *en masse*, and we prefer to only do things like that *after* we've given the community a chance to weigh in. Also, it's good to check that there aren't a bunch of off-topic questions hiding under suspicious tags while we're doing it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that I went over my head doing it manually and don't ask a community before doing it. Mostly because there were just handful of questions. Thanks for your input, and I will be doing things better next time.

Comment: I am surprised with negative score of this post. To me getting rid of "workplace" seems to be a great idea because it sounds awfully misleading (broken window). Another thing I don't understand is the fuss about editing. 50 question edits at a site that gets 8K new questions a day looks like far below the noticeable level of turbulence, I am not even sure that every change like that is worth a meta post (how many 50-questions tags are there, hundreds if not thousands). Personally I'd probably spread this retagging more or less evenly over 3-5 days but that's minor thing

Comment: @gnat:  I'm not as chuffed at this by earlier efforts that happened this week, but the idea is that "burnination" doesn't just mean "remove the tag".  If you're going to edit the post, you have to be thorough about it.  This is only calling the thoroughness into question, and nothing more.

Comment: so, if OP did thorough edits instead of only changing the tag, it would be okay - do I understand you correctly @Makoto?

Comment: @gnat: It certainly wouldn't be that big of a deal. We'd want an audit trail, but if it were done well,I personally wouldn't complain.

Comment: I see, that makes sense - thanks @Makoto

Comment: What's funny to me is that, despite the usual Meta theories that get trotted out for want of evidence about how tags with obvious names are "misleading" or "broken windows", this tag *wasn't*. Igor says all the questions with it were actually about the Facebook product. Yet...the theories are still being trotted out, even when we have clear evidence that they are wrong in this case.

Comment: @CodyGray if mod tools allow to check deleted questions in the tag, try this first. How long would you expect some career advice question mistagged with "workplace" stay visible on a site

Comment: The proper solution might have been to simply rename the tag, if all questions with the tag was about Facebook. It was not a meta tag but it was an ambiguous tag, which is also bad.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case there's more looking-at to do...here's a list of (most) of the questions which had their tags removed.  We should look at these to see if they're on topic.

- [Facebook graph api in workplace: group post with mentioning users](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42147687)
- [Can you embed the feed from a Facebook Workplace in an iframe?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42363230)
- [Facebook Workplace API authentication](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42567559)
- [Workplace custom integration authentification](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42670062)
- [Publish Facebook Workplace's custom integration](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43556474)
- [Are bots for Workplace by Facebook supported via the Facebook channel on Microsoft Bot Framework?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43637134)
- [Are groups in Workplace by Facebook supported via the Facebook channel on Microsoft Bot Framework](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44058021)
- [Facebook Workplace webhook call back url fixing](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44820195)
- [Access Workplace (Internal facebook) data through API](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45310607)
- [How to authenticate FB Workplace Account Management API in PHP?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45406141)
- [Calling facebook workplace api](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45618390)
- [How to use workplace graph api to post on multi company group?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45688414)
- [Facebook workplace API in Python](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45718022)
- [How to access community id in facebook workplace?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45721091)
- [Workplace Graph API - send message in group chat](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45937257)
- [Facebook Workplace - Custom facebook notification](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45959703)